# multipleDefine Error in logcat - dojo Mobile

Tags: android, dojo

> While executing the code below I am getting multipleDefine script error in >>logcat. It points to line 21 which is - "APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "btnClickLoad",
>
> > LogCat Error-[Info Console]"Error: mulitpleDefine "
> >
> > > What is the possible reason and and should i fix it

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>btnClickLoad</title>
                <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
                <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
                    <!--
                        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
                    -->
                <link href="worklight/worklight.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <script>
                // Define WL namespace.
                var WL = WL ? WL : {};
                /**
                 * WLClient configuration variables.
                 * Values are injected by the deployer that packs the gadget.
                 */
                 WL.StaticAppProps = {
           "APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "btnClickLoad",
           "APP_ID": "btnClickLoad",
           "APP_SERVICES_URL": "\/apps\/services\/",
           "APP_VERSION": "1.0",
           "ENVIRONMENT": "android",
           "LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE": "embedded",
           "WORKLIGHT_NATIVE_VERSION": "3024537711",
           "WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "6.3.0.0",
           "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL": "\/apps\/services\/api\/btnClickLoad\/android\/"
        };
        </script>
                <script src="worklight/cordova.js"></script>
                <script src="worklight/wljq.js"></script>
                <script src="worklight/worklight.js"></script>
                <script src="worklight/checksum.js"></script>
                <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
                    <script src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <script data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="http://10.97.62.72:9988/dojo10/btnClickLoad/btnClickLoad/android/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

           <!-- Add -->
           <link href="dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"
                data-dojo-config="mblThemeFiles: ['base','Button']"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
           require([
            "dijit/registry",
            "dojox/mobile/ViewController",
            "dojox/mobile/parser",
            "dojox/mobile",
            "dojox/mobile/Button",
            "dojox/mobile/View",
            "dojox/mobile/Button",
            "dojox/mobile/Heading",
            "dojox.mobile.ScrollableView",


        ], function(registry, ViewController){
            var vc = ViewController.getInstance();
            onBtn1Clicked = function(e){
                // the external view is loaded under the "container" view.
                vc.openExternalView({
                    url:"load.html",
                    transition:"slide"
                }, registry.byId("container").containerNode);
            };
        });

           </script>

           <!-- end -->

            </head>
            <body style="display: none;">
                <div data-dojo-props="selected:true" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0">
                        <!--application UI goes here-->
                        Hello MobileFirst
                        <div id="home" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
            <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">Home</h1>
            <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" id="btn1" style="margin:5px;"
                    data-dojo-props='onClick:onBtn1Clicked'>Load external view</button>
        </div>
        <div id="container" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
            <!-- An external view is loaded here when clicking the button above -->
        </div>
                    </div>
                <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js twice, if you remove the first one it should fix the problem.

```
<script src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```